# A question on line XV.167 of Ovid's Metamorphoses re 'eque'

Tags: ovidius

My question concerns the use of the word 'eque'.  As far as I can see it is the vocative of 'equus' but that clearly doesn't make sense and I can find no other meaning of the word in the dictionary.  Perhaps it is a typo for

> spiritusque feris humana in corpora transit

But that would ruin the hexameters.

> omnia mutantur, nihil interit: errat et illinc
> huc venit, hinc illuc, et quoslibet occupat artus
> spiritus **eque** feris humana in corpora transit
> inque feras noster

The translation that I have seems to have ignored the word:

> The moving soul
> may wander, coming from that spot to this,
> from this to that, in changed possession live
> in any limbs whatever.

Also, there's a great rendition of this poem found here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXGmXCV0WwQ&t=23s

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, note that the first vowel must be long, to fit the meter:

> spīritus **ēque** ferīs humāna in corpora transit

This rules out the vocative of *equus*, which has a short vowel there.

Instead, this seems to be **the preposition *ē* plus the enclitic *-que***. (Something else plus the enclitic is always a good option to consider when you see a strange-looking word ending in *-que*.)

Rearranging this line into a more natural-sounding sentence:

> spīritus **ē-que** ferīs in corpora humāna transit
> *The spirit moves **both from** beasts to human bodies*

(But of course that's no longer a hexameter.)

For more confirmation, look at the start of the next line, which uses a parallel construction:

> **in-que** ferās…
> ***and [back] into** beasts…*

Comment: Excellent, I hadn't though of that one. Thanks.